# PHP remove newline in string for both Linux and Windows

Tags: php, newline

Currently I have to call

```
    $html = str_replace($search="\r\n", $replace='', $subject=$html);
    $html = str_replace($search="\n",   $replace='', $subject=$html);
```

to remove `new line` character in string `$html`. Is there a better/shorter way?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=replace+newlines+php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that at once by using an array:

```
$search = array("\r\n", "\n");
$result = str_replace($search, $replace='', $subject=$html);
```

See [`str_replace`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/str_replace).

Comment: Yes, there is a little gap not having this as copy and paste read code. I would generally assume that gap is likely to be closed by the reader of the answer. If you run into a concrete problem dealing with it, just let me know.

Comment: The answer is misleading as some users may think - due to the way your answer is written - that `str_replace()` modifies the *subject*.

Comment: @ring0: Not for the (old) code, because subject is not passed as a variable, but only it's value as the result of the expression. As no variable is being passed, it can not be passed by reference which is the precondition for the modification you describe. Also if you're unsure, I had left a link to the function documentation. And also, yes, there is now `$result` to not even make some users start thinking. BTW you can improve existing answers if you feel so.

Answer (score 10):

Try:

```
$html = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $html);
```